# Android Wear Os Scan for Bluetooth devices

Tags: android, permissions, bluetooth, wear-os

I am trying to make some kind of indoor navigation, just by using a wear os device (Pixel Smartwatch) and no phone.
So far I am facing issues requesting the permissions for bluetooth.
I started with reading the [docs](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/connectivity/bluetooth), sometimes it is a little confusing to me, if all those functions apply to wear os or android for smartphones only.

This is part of my manifest:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH_ADVERTISE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH_SCAN" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH_CONNECT" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH_ADMIN" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
```

I might not need all of them, but since it did not work with a subset of them, I kept on adding everything related, without success so far.

This is my one and only activity so far:

```
val permissions = arrayOf(
    Manifest.permission.BLUETOOTH,
    Manifest.permission.BLUETOOTH_ADMIN,
    Manifest.permission.BLUETOOTH_ADVERTISE,
    Manifest.permission.BLUETOOTH_CONNECT,
    Manifest.permission.BLUETOOTH_SCAN,
    Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION,
    Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION,
)

override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    ...
    val permissionsLeft = ArrayList<String>()

    permissions.forEach {
        if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, it) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            permissionsLeft.add(it)
            Log.i("TEST", "permission missing: $it")
        }
    }
    if (permissionsLeft.isNotEmpty()) {
       
        ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, permissionsLeft.toTypedArray(), 1);
    }
```

Only the first run of this app (after deleting it), shows a dialog to confirm the permissions. But the permission that needs acknowledgement is the location one only. There is nothing about any of the Bluetooth permissions. At least not visible for the user, the **BLUETOOTH** and **BLUETOOTH_ADMIN** are granted according my Logcat output. So after confirming the dialog once, the next run (Logcat) tells me, only the **BLUETOOTH_ADVERTISE**, **BLUETOOTH_CONNECT**, **BLUETOOTH_SCAN** are missing.
But I can't make them appear in the dialog neither are they in the permission settings of the app listed.

if I override the **onRequestPermissionsResult**

```
override fun onRequestPermissionsResult(
    requestCode: Int,
    permissions: Array<String>,
    grantResults: IntArray
) {
    super.onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults)
    when (requestCode) {
        REQUEST_CODE -> {
            if (grantResults.isNotEmpty() && grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                Log.i("TEST", "Granted")
            } else {
                Log.i("TEST", "Not Granted")
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The remaining permissions always end in the **Not Granted** branch, without any user interaction. I am grateful for any tips. Please keep in mind, this is for a smartwatch and not a regular smartphone

------ UPDATE ------

Turns out even with those permissions not granted I can use the **bluetoothAdapter.startDiscovery()** and more functions that are not suppossed to work. I don't know if this is a bug, an exceptions for wear os or I don't get it.

[image: Requires permission check]

With the generated permission check, it will not execute the **device!!.name**, since the permission is not granted. But when I add       **@SuppressLint("MissingPermission")** to the function and don't check for the permission it works without any problem...

Answer (score 0):

did you make any progress with your ble-scanner or are you still having problems? the permission usage on the watch are kind of annoying but you should be able to use all of the stuff you need. location is always weired, but since ble is often used to retrieve a location of something this makes sort of sence.

I'm also working on a watch standalone project and need to get callbacks if i get out of range of a beacon or other bt device.
i have worked on a lot of bt projects and hope i can implement this on the watch.

so if you are struggeling let me know, maybe i can help